# How can I fetch the entire row with the max value in a column of a query with a nested select?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with a query in SQL. My query is something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.attribute, t.name, t.date
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE
UNION
...) t
WHERE ...
GROUP BY t.attribute
```

What I want is to fetch all the rows with the latest date for each attribute (date can be null, and then it's the latest).
I know I can create a temporary table, but I want to avoid it if possible.
I also want not to nest again the same query of the FROM neither in the WHERE nor in a JOIN.
Is there any way?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide table1 and table2 rows to work with.

Comment: I don't understand, do you refer to the data? if you want the columns, you can assume they are the same in table1, table2 and t

Comment: yup please just edit your question with data @alexrn

Comment: I don't have any data, that query is an example of a problem. I think that the solution should be independent of the data.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way of doing it using CTE (Common table expressions):

```
;WITH Maxtable1
    AS (SELECT attribute
            , name
            , MAX(t.date) AS MaxDate
        FROM   table1
        GROUP BY attribute
             , name),
    Maxtable2
    AS (SELECT attribute
            , name
            , MAX(t.date) AS MaxDate
        FROM   table2
        GROUP BY attribute
             , name),
             .
             .
             .
    Maxtable<n>
    AS (SELECT attribute
            , name
            , MAX(t.date) AS MaxDate
        FROM   table<n>
        GROUP BY attribute
             , name),
    DetailTable1
    AS (SELECT id
            , attribute
            , name
            , date
        FROM   table1
             INNER JOIN Maxtable1 ON table1.attribute = Maxtable1.attribute
                                AND table1.name = Maxtable1.name
                                AND table1.date = Maxtable1.date),
    DetailTable2
    AS (SELECT id
            , attribute
            , name
            , date
        FROM   table2
             INNER JOIN Maxtable2 ON table2.attribute = Maxtable2.attribute
                                AND table2.name = Maxtable2.name
                                AND table2.date = Maxtable2.date),
             .
             .
             .
    DetailTable<n>
    AS (SELECT id
            , attribute
            , name
            , date
        FROM   table<n>
             INNER JOIN Maxtable<n> ON table<n>.attribute = Maxtable<n>.attribute
                                AND table<n>.name = Maxtable<n>.name
                                AND table<n>.date = Maxtable<n>.date)
    SELECT *
    FROM   DetailTable1
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM   DetailTable2
    UNION
    .
    .
    .
    SELECT *
    FROM   DetailTable<n>;
```

Answer (score 0):

With [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) you can use a window function:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.attribute, t2.name, t2.date
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.attribute, t1.name, t1.date, 
           row_number() over (partition by t1.attribute order by t1.date desc) as rn
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE ...
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM table2
      WHERE ...
      UNION
      ...
   ) t1
) t2
where rn = 1;
```

Alternatively use a common table expression to avoid the nesting of derived tables:

```
with data as (
  SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE ...
  UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE ...
  UNION
), numbered as (
  SELECT id, attribute, name, date, 
         row_number() over (partition by t1.attribute order by t1.date desc) as rn
  FROM data
)
SELECT id, attribute, name, date
from numbered 
where rn = 1;
```